# Simplifying complex expression with Mathematica

Tags: complex

I want do get the imaginary part of

```
Exp[I*t]/(1-Exp[I*t])
```

I've tried to do this

```
Im[ComplexExpand[Exp[I*t]/(1-Exp[I*t])]]
```

but the result still contains

```
Im[Cos[t]/((1 - Cos[t])^2 + Sin[t]^2) - 
   Cos[t]^2/((1 - Cos[t])^2 + Sin[t]^2) - 
   Sin[t]^2/((1 - Cos[t])^2 + Sin[t]^2)]
```

which in fact is 0 (t is a real variable). How can I convince *Mathematica* to get rid of this part of the expression?

Comment: While I don't know much about Mathematica, that expression, as written, is -1/2, for all t where f[t] is defined, not 0.

Comment: Did you know there's a mathematica.stackexchange? I've flagged for migrating it there.

Comment: Mathematica doesn't know you are assuming t is Real until you tell it. Simplify[Im[ComplexExpand[Exp[I*t]/(1-Exp[I*t])]],t \\[Element] Reals] and then you are assuming that the denominator is not zero. Simplify[Im[ComplexExpand[Exp[I*t]/(1 - Exp[I*t])]], 
 t \\[Element] Reals && Cos[t] != 1]

Comment: `Simplify @ ComplexExpand[Im[Exp[I*t]/(1 - Exp[I*t])]]`?

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the procedure:

Putting Im under ComplexExpand you get immediately

```
In[182]:= ComplexExpand[Im[Exp[I*t]/(1 - Exp[I*t])]]

Out[182]= Sin[t]/((1 - Cos[t])^2 + Sin[t]^2)
```

Simplifying this leads to the final result

```
In[183]:= Simplify[%]

Out[183]= 1/2 Cot[t/2]
```

Treating the real part similarly leads to

```
In[184]:= ComplexExpand[Re[Exp[I*t]/(1 - Exp[I*t])]]//Simplify

Out[185]= -(1/2)
```

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: It would be educational to mention why :)

Comment: @Kuba: It is requested to calculate the imaginary part of a complex function f(t) of the real argument t. This can be done efficiently in MMA as shown. Notice that ComplexExpand simplifies a function assuming all its parameters to be real.