# Problem with Assuming

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I have some involved complex expressions, relying upon constants and the variables `t`, `C[i]`,$i=1,2,3$.

Using Refine, I try to compute the Im part of my expression, assuming that `t`, `C[i]` are Reals.

I expected that Im would provide a "real" expression.
Even when `FullSimplify` is enrolled, `Im` remains unevaluated!
Below I give an example package-fragment:

```
Ims2A1ref=FullSimplify[
  Refine[Im[s2A1f[t]],Assumptions->C[1]>=0&&C[2]>=0 &&C[3]>=0 && t>=0]
]
(* 10000000000*C[3]*Im[E^(2*ArcTanh[(E^((t - 2*C[2])/100000)*Sqrt[1 + 10000000000*C[1]^2])/(-1 + (100000*I)*C[1])] + (t - (50000*I)*ArcTan[(E^((t - 2*C[2])/100000)*Sqrt[1 + 10000000000*C[1]^2])/(-I + 100000*C[1])] + 2*C[2])/25000)/(2*E^((t + 2*C[2])/50000)*(-1 + 10000000000*C[1]^2) + E^(t/25000)*(1 + 10000000000*C[1]^2) + E^(C[2]/12500)*(1 + 10000000000*C[1]^2))] *)
```

My problem involves Assumptions, it is not a duplicate of [Simplifying complex expression with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52269/simplifying-complex-expression-with-mathematica).

My expressions are the components of one Mathematica solution to a system of 3 ODEs. They depend upon constants C[i], i=1,2,3.
Substituting C[i] with Ci does not solve my problem.

I think that my Assumptions are not well taken into consideration!?

Bob Hanlon suggested a solution based upon ComplexExpand. Unfortunately it does not work. See the example below.

In[13]:= s2Kf[t]

Out[13]= (1/1000000000000-E^((t-2 C[2])/5000)/1000000000000+C[1]^2/10000+(E^((t-2 C[2])/5000) C[1]^2)/10000-√(-((E^((t-2 C[2])/5000) C[1]^2)/10000000000000000)-(E^((t-2 C[2])/2500) C[1]^2)/5000000000000000-(E^((3 (t-2 C[2]))/5000) C[1]^2)/10000000000000000-(E^((t-2 C[2])/5000) C[1]^4)/100000000-(E^((t-2 C[2])/2500) C[1]^4)/50000000-(E^((3 (t-2 C[2]))/5000) C[1]^4)/100000000))/(-(1/100000000)+E^((t-2 C[2])/5000)/50000000-E^((t-2 C[2])/2500)/100000000-C[1]^2-2 E^((t-2 C[2])/5000) C[1]^2-E^((t-2 C[2])/2500) C[1]^2)

In[14]:= Ims2Kxpnd=s2Kf[t]//ComplexExpand[#,TargetFunctions->{Re,Im}]&//FullSimplify[#,Thread[{C[1],C[2],C[3],t}>=0]]& (* I is in the output: useless *)

Out[14]= -((100000000 E^((t+C[2])/5000) C[1]^2+E^((3 C[2])/5000) (1+100000000 C[1]^2))/(10000 (10000 E^((t+4 C[2])/10000) C[1] Sqrt[-1-100000000 C[1]^2]+E^((t+C[2])/5000) (-1+100000000 C[1]^2)+10000 I E^(3 t/10000) C[1] Sqrt[1+100000000 C[1]^2]+E^((3 C[2])/5000) (1+100000000 C[1]^2))))

Comment: Are you aware C[1] and C are reserved symbols and not generic variables?

Comment: @bills It is possible that the `C[1]` et al arose as outputs from whatever is computed by `s2A1f`. Your implicit suggestion that they not otherwise be in user code is of course quite on target though.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau -- you are correct -- but without knowing anything about s2A1f, it's hard to see how anyone can help.

Comment: @bills I agree with you. I guess one could start with the output indicated (`10000000000*C[3]*`...) and try to work with that. But that would not replace knowing whatever it is `FullSImplify` is getting as input.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Using `C[1]`, etc. should be fine for as long as no values are assigned to them, no? Functions that generate these constants should detect if they already exist in the expression automatically avoid conflict. E.g., `DSolve[x'[t] == -C[1] x[t], x[t], t]` generates `C[2]`, not `C[1]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, using `C[1]` in `Assuming` is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = 10000000000*C[3]*
   Im[E^(2*ArcTanh[(E^((t - 2*C[2])/100000)*
             Sqrt[1 + 10000000000*C[1]^2])/(-1 + (100000*I)*
              C[1])] + (t - (50000*I)*
            ArcTan[(E^((t - 2*C[2])/100000)*
                Sqrt[1 + 10000000000*C[1]^2])/(-I + 100000*C[1])] + 
           2*C[2])/25000)/(2*
        E^((t + 2*C[2])/50000)*(-1 + 10000000000*C[1]^2) + 
       E^(t/25000)*(1 + 10000000000*C[1]^2) + 
       E^(C[2]/12500)*(1 + 10000000000*C[1]^2))];

expr2 = expr // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
  FullSimplify[#, Thread[{C[1], C[2], C[3], t} >= 0]] &

(* -((4000000000000000 E^((t + 2 C[2])/
     20000) (-E^(t/50000) + E^(C[2]/25000)) C[1] Sqrt[
     1 + 10000000000 C[1]^2]
      C[3])/(2 E^((t + 2 C[2])/50000) (-1 + 10000000000 C[1]^2) + 
     E^(t/25000) (1 + 10000000000 C[1]^2) + 
     E^(C[2]/12500) (1 + 10000000000 C[1]^2))^2) *)
```

**EDIT** For the second example,

```
s2Kf[t_] = (1/1000000000000 - E^((t - 2 C[2])/5000)/1000000000000 + 
     C[1]^2/10000 + (E^((t - 2 C[2])/5000) C[1]^2)/
      10000 - \[Sqrt](-((E^((t - 2 C[2])/5000) C[1]^2)/
           10000000000000000) - (E^((t - 2 C[2])/2500) C[1]^2)/
         5000000000000000 - (E^((3 (t - 2 C[2]))/5000) C[1]^2)/
         10000000000000000 - (E^((t - 2 C[2])/5000) C[1]^4)/
         100000000 - (E^((t - 2 C[2])/2500) C[1]^4)/
         50000000 - (E^((3 (t - 2 C[2]))/5000) C[1]^4)/100000000))/(-(1/
        100000000) + E^((t - 2 C[2])/5000)/50000000 - 
     E^((t - 2 C[2])/2500)/100000000 - C[1]^2 - 
     2 E^((t - 2 C[2])/5000) C[1]^2 - E^((t - 2 C[2])/2500) C[1]^2);
```

For this to be real, the argument of the `Sqrt` must be nonnegative.

```
Cases[s2Kf[t], Sqrt[x_] :> (x >= 0), Infinity] // 
 FullSimplify[#, C[1] >= 0 && C[2] >= 0 && t >= 0] &

(* {C[1]^2 <= 0} *)
```

Consequently, since `C[1]` is nonnegative then `C[1]` must be `0` for the expression to be real. For this special case,

```
Ims2Kxpnd = s2Kf[t] /. C[1] -> 0 // FullSimplify

(* 1/(10000 (-1 + E^((t - 2 C[2])/5000))) *)
```

If `C[1]  !=  0` then the expression is complex and the simplified form is

```
s2Kf[t] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
 FullSimplify[#, C[1] > 0 && C[2] >= 0 && t >= 0] &

(* (-1 + E^((t - 2 C[2])/5000) - 100000000 C[1]^2 - 
   100000000 E^((t - 2 C[2])/5000) C[1]^2 + 
   10000 I E^((t - 2 C[2])/10000) (1 + E^((t - 2 C[2])/5000)) C[1] Sqrt[
    1 + 100000000 C[1]^2])/(10000 ((-1 + E^((t - 2 C[2])/5000))^2 + 
     100000000 (1 + E^((t - 2 C[2])/5000))^2 C[1]^2)) *)
```

Comment: Dear Bob, thank you very much for your suggestion. Unfortunately it does not work. I added an example by editing my question. Best.

Comment: Thank you Bob for your interesting analysis. I must work out better my expressions. Best.